# Is it possible to define a random number in jinja template itself

Tags: jinja2

I have a jinja template file like this:

```
<a href="http://{{ domain }}:8006/{{ path1 }}/{{ path2 }}/?v=1638364458370" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Is it possible to make the random number update to a new one every time?

Something like:

```
<a href="http://{{ domain }}:8006/{{ path1 }}/{{ path2 }}/?v={{ rand() }}" target="_blank">link</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible using [`range()`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-globals.range), to generate a sequence and feed it to the [`random`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.random) filter.
You could even go further and use [`format`](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/templates/#jinja-filters.format) to zero-pad the randomly generated number.

Given:

```
{{ '{:0=13}'.format(range(0, 9999999999999) | random) }}
```

This yields a 0-padded random number between 0000000000000 and 9999999999999.